# How to convert map scale 1:10000 to nearest zoom level 16 scale 1:9028

Tags: arcgis-server, convert, tiles, scale, tile-map-service

I am making tile map service port for this map http://mapserver.geology.sk/sbd/. 
When you max zoom this map, you will get scale 1:10000. Tile size is 256px.
You can check it here http://mapserver.geology.sk/sbd/proxy.jsp?http://hparc:8399/arcgis/rest/services/Podklady/Podklad3/MapServer/tile/10/51622/48898

This tile map system is custom only for this web map so I need make port to match TMS standard. My question is how to convert this image map tile 256px 1:100000 to match scale 1:9028 which correspond to zoom level 16 and has tile size 256px.

Comment: Are you using ArcGis server as wms backend?